# Apache in an AWS Instance not starting

Tags: networking, server, apache2, amazon-ec2, aws

I had an instance with AWS, decided to upgrade the plan of that instance and now my instance is not working properly with 2 sites that I had.

I detached the static IP from the old instance and put it on the new instance. 
It should be working fine? Unfortunately, it’s not.

The static IP address used to give me the default Bitnami congratulation page. But now it gives me Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page.

I use this command to attempt to restart apache2:

```
~$ sudo apachectl restart
```

It gave me this error message:

```
httpd not running, trying to start
(98)Address already in use: AH00073: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00073: make_sock: unable to listen for connections on address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Edit: Also the domain name I had pointed to this static IP address is not resolving. (The static IP is pointed to the new instances already.)

Answer (score 0):

```
service nginx stop
```

and try now. I am guessing that you have installed the nginx which is using the port 80  and that is why the apache cannot work.

As for the domain you have to point this to the new IP..

Comment: not sure, the domain is pointed at the static ip. its the same ip for the new instance. I'm not sure about nginx, i just created an instance of the snapshot from my other instance that I attempted to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which process is listening at the port 80 using the command `netstat`:

```
sudo netstat -tlpn | grep :80
```

In my case, it’s `apache2`.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80         0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      11164/apache2
```

If you find a different process is using it (such as `nginx` as [suggested by another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1121081/250300)), stop the process using the command `kill <PID>` or `service <name> stop`.

Comment: I did what you suggested this what I got.  `tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1491/apache2`

Comment: It means Apache is running and waiting for IPv6 connections. Could you edit your question with details on _how_ you tried to restart Apache (exact command)?

Comment: edited my question, I used `~S sudo apachectl restart`